# Етимологія слова "андрути"

Tags: етимологія

Цікавить етимологія слова "андрути" ("[вафлі](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/187/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82)"). Часто доводиться зустрічати це слово на сайтах присвячених кулінарії (наприклад [тут](http://panistefa.com/andruty-tse-vam-ne-yakis-tam-peremashheni-vafli/)), однак його пошук в [етимологічному словнику](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1982/EtSlUkrM_1982.pdf) не дав ніяких результатів. Також цього слова немає ані в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/), ані в [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Німецького походження посередництвом польської

> [andrut](//pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/andrut#pl)
>
> (1.1) *daw.* „andrót” *zamiast* „on(d)rót” (*z wstawionym* d) < *niem.* [ohne](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ohne#German) + [Rot](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rot#German) → (*o waflu*, *opłatku*) bez rumieńca, bez przyrumienienia
> (1.2) od (1.1)

Де:

- *ohne* — без
- *Rot* — червоний

Згадані словники не мають, бо [вузькозахідне](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53392/1060192.html):

> андру́т (*перев. мн.* андрути) *кул.* вафля